# 'The talk was about' vs. 'We were talking about'

Tags: word-usage

I want to point someone about theme of conversation with another person. What sentence is correct?

> The talk was about airplanes.

or

> We were talking about airplanes.

I want to make accent on a theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are just fine, but if you wish to stress the topic of conversation, the first version is a bit stronger.

You could also say that airplanes were the topic of conversation.

Answer (score 1):

To me, "talk" indicates that one person was giving a presentation on airplanes. That might just be me coming from an academic background where that's the definition of "a talk". So if you want to use the grammatical form of the first version, use "conversation" instead.

However, I'd advise against it since it is very impersonal and lifeless.